# Algorithm for solving decimal exponents without fractions

Tags: math, arbitrary-precision

Could someone explain the steps involved in solving something like 2^2.2 if fractions couldn't be used, such as in an infinite precision calculation?

Comment: What do you mean by "fractions" in this context?  A typical approach to computing arbitrary powers is to go via the log domain.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I mean without having to convert the decimal to a fraction to solve, all the examples I have seen for decimal exponents would always involve changing the decimal exponent into a fraction. For example if you were doing 2^2.2 on a piece of paper without a calculator then how would you calculate 2^(1/5)?

Answer (score 2):

In the general case  `a^b` where `^` is exponentiation (not XOR), and a and b are real numbers:

```
pow(a,b) = exp( b * log(a) ) 
exp(x)   = sum[n = 0->inf]  x^n / n!
ln(x)    = sum[n = 1->inf]  (x-1)^n / n
x^n      = n == 0  ? 1   // unless x == 0
          (n%2==0) ? x^(n/2) * x^(n/2) 
          othewrwise x*x^(n-1)  
          // faster than loop for large n,
```

This requries two series that you need to terminate at a certain precision, but the exponentiation is only with natural numbers.

You also have to deal with sign of a and b (`a^-b = 1/(a^b)`), zero values etc.

Answer (score 0):

A typical implementation of `pow(x,y)` (i.e. `x^y`) involves computing `exp(y*log(x))`.  No fractions involved.